# Ajuda VBA Excel excluir linha em outro arquivo

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Olá!
Estou usando o código VBA abaixo que exclui a linha da planinha caso encontre os valores "PAC" ou "Sedex"
Ele funciona na planinha ativa mas preciso também que execute em uma série de arquivos (tag1.xlxs, tag2.xlxs, etc...) localizados em outra pasta.
Como fazer esta referência?

```
Function ApagarLinha(ByVal firstRow As Integer, ByVal lastRow As Integer, ByVal criteriaColumn As Integer, ByVal criteria As String) As Integer
    Dim deletedRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    deletedRows = 0
    With ActiveSheet
        i = firstRow
        While i < lastRow
            If CStr(.Cells(i, criteriaColumn).Value) = criteria Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
                deletedRows = deletedRows + 1
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Wend
    End With
    ApagarLinha = deletedRows
End Function

Sub CorrigirTAG()
    Call ApagarLinha(1, 20, 1, "PAC")
    Call ApagarLinha(1, 20, 1, "Sedex")
End Sub
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia Atelier,

Com o `function` realmente não ira funcionar, pois, ela não consegue abrir e trabalhar com outras planilhas.

O ideal seria você criar uma `sub`.
Montei esse exemplo abaixo de como funcionaria:

```
Sub Iniciar_Processo()
    'Aqui voce irá colocar o caminho com o nome da pasta de trabalho e o nome da planilha que deseja efetuar a busca e a exclusão
    Call deletarLinha("C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\planilha_terceira.XLSX", "Planilha11")
End Sub

Sub deletarLinha(ByVal Caminho As String, ByVal Planilha As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    'Abre a pasta de trabalho
    On Error GoTo tratamento1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Caminho)
    On Error GoTo -1
    
    'Inicia o objeto ws com a planilha da pasta de trabalho
    On Error GoTo tratamento2
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(Planilha)
    On Error GoTo -1

    primeira_Linha = 2 'Primeira linha da tabela, modifique caso não seja a linha 2
    ultima_Linha = ws.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row 'A ultima linha ja é feito uma busca automatica.
    Coluna_FRETE = "F" 'Coloque a leta da coluna que está os campos de frete
    
    qnt_Linhas_Deletadas = 0
    
    'busca e deleta as linhas com uma das condições sendo verdadeira.
    For i = primeira_Linha To ultima_Linha
        If ws.Range(Coluna_FRETE & i).Value = "PAC" Or ws.Range(Coluna_FRETE & i).Value = "SEDEX" Then
            ws.Rows(i).Delete
            qnt_Linhas_Deletadas = qnt_Linhas_Deletadas + 1
            i = i - 1
            ultima_Linha = ultima_Linha - 1
        End If
    Next
    
    'salva a pasta de trabalho e fecha.
    wb.Save
    wb.Close
    
    'exibe uma msg de conclusão e quantas linhas foram deletadas.
    MsgBox "Foram deletada(s) " & qnt_Linhas_Deletadas & " linha(s)", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
    
'tratamento de exceções
tratamento1:
    MsgBox "Pasta de trabalho não encontrada.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
tratamento2:
    wb.Close
    MsgBox "Planilha não encontrada na pasta de trabalho.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado Romssnes!